# How do I make each list in the list of lists sort in ascending order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following lists:

```
[[1, 5], [3, 7], [4, 2], [7, 8], [6, 3], [2, 5], [4, 1]]
```

And I am trying to sort them by the first value, after making the list go in ascending order:

**Desired output:**

```
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [7, 8]]
```

However, `list.sort()` only gives the following:

```
>>> mylist = [[1, 5], [3, 7], [4, 2], [7, 8], [6, 3], [2, 5], [4, 1]]
>>> mylist.sort()
>>> mylist
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 7], [4, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3], [7, 8]]
>>>
```

Of course, I could always loop each list in the list of lists and sort it:

```
>>> mylist
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 7], [4, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3], [7, 8]]
>>> for k in range(len(mylist)):
...     mylist[k] = sorted(mylist[k])
... 
>>> mylist
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 7], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> sorted(mylist)
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [7, 8]]
```

But is there a one liner to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little better than your loop:

```
for sublist in mylist:
    sublist.sort()

mylist.sort()
```

Of course, this changes each sublist *in-place*.  Judging by your examples, it looks like that is what you want, but I thought I should mention it just in case.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
sorted(sorted(sublist) for sublist in mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner that does the sort in-place

```
>>> mylist = [[1, 5], [3, 7], [4, 2], [7, 8], [6, 3], [2, 5], [4, 1]]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x:x.sort() or x)
>>> mylist
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [7, 8]]
```